# Delete Empty Series VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to delete empty series from Excel chart. I have tried this code but there is problem with if statement.

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = 0 Then
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that the item SeriesCollection is a Collection of Points on the Chart, so maybe loop again over the points in that SerieCollection item  and check if the Value of the point is equal to 0 ?

Comment: even empty data sets are arrays... try this: `If UBound(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values) <= 1 Then`

Comment: Yes my bad, the SeriesCollection item is an array that holds the values of the points

Comment: Just for your consideration: hidden rows are not shown on a chart. So, it would be sufficient to hide these rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove blank cells?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
```

or if you need to remove entire rows or columns where you have blank data in a range you could use something like this;

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
```